# Apache NiFi Create Process Group with my own ID

Tags: apache-nifi

**Background**

According to the NiFi API documentation, `id` is an optional field on a create process group request:

```
POST /process-groups/{id}/process-groups
{
  "revision": {
    "version" : 0
  },
  "id" : "8a698dd8-7947-43fd-8bdd-2d4f26ee3329",
  "component": {
    "name": "my-process-group-foo"
  }
}
```

This will create a new process group as a child of the `{id}` process group.  I would assume that by passing in a GUID as part of the request body, the resulting process group would be created using the GUID that I passed in.

Through testing though I've come to realize that the process group that is created is assigned an `id` by NiFi and does not use the `id` that I've passed in.

Response from above example (condensed)

```
{
  "revision": {
    "version": 1,
  },
  "id": "7d47183d-0173-1000-ffff-fffff6dceb50",
  "component": {
    "id": "7d47183d-0173-1000-ffff-fffff6dceb50",
    "parentGroupId": "348a629f-0173-1000-a243-b2203c5b8272",
    "name": "my-process-group-foo"
  }
}
```

Instead of creating my process group with the id I asked for it assigned a completely new id.

If I try add my `id` inside of the `component` object I get a 400 error `Process group ID cannot be specified.`

**Question**

Is there a way to create a process group using an `id` that I specify?

I am currently trying to figure out how to update versioned processes from NiFi Registry when I have the same process running on multiple clusters (different data centers).  My original thought was if I could create the process group with the same `id` on all of the clusters, I could then have my CI/CD pipeline create a version update request, confident that the same `id` is on all the clusters.

**References**

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no you cannot specify the UUID, it will always be assigned by NiFi. I believe the field is marked as optional because you can supply it without generating an error, but it will be ignored - Such as as when you upload templates or other flow definitions.